# Datasheet of transistor 37428 from RCA

Tags: datasheet

Somebody can send mee the datasheet of RCA 37428 transistor. 
Thank you!

Comment: Why not simply ask RCA?

Comment: Please post a photo of the part in question, marking readable.

Comment: I mean, yes, these are very probably antique transistors, but to be honest, it'll be easier to measure their properties than to extrapolate them from a datasheet plus 40 years of aging...

Comment: I didn't know RCA even made transistors any more.  You might be better off getting parts from a manufacturer who is still in that business.

Comment: @MarcusMüller RCA ceased to exist as a company in 1986. So it'd be rather hard to ask them…

Comment: @duskwuff -- yeah, ST ate their discrete product lines, and Harris (now Intersil) got their IC product lines

Answer (score 2):

I have an old cross-reference from RCA that says that a suitable replacement is the SK3024 transistor. Some characteristics of the latter can be found in [this datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/270/501158_DS.pdf). (NPN, 5W, 1A, 100V)